# Android AdMob Native Express into ListView

Tags: android, listview, admob, native-ads

i've a problem when AdMob Express Native Ads load first time and refresh banner.
My code is the same that [github google native ads](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/admob/NativeExpressExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/gms/ads/nativeexpressexample/MainActivity.java) i've only put adpter listview control this choise:

```
if (position == 0) {
      // put admob view initialization here
}else{
      // listview view element
}
```

In this case i see my listview become in some parts with black background:

[image]

Where are my errors?
Thanks a lot